# read file of 10 lines of integer, put them in a array, and output the array

Tags: c

1. In this program, i want to let user to input 2 arguments, the number 
         of integer,and the file name.

   1. the file has 10 lines of integer value.
   2. read the file, and put it to inArray[];
   3. and then output it as the end;

      notes: For the complete program, i want to make a program that 
            will scan a file consists of random integer,and then sort 
            them in ascend order, and print out the first 10 percent
             of the sorted integer.

      Error: For now, i want to test if it can read the file and put values
            into the inArray properly, but its keep getting errors.

      ```
        warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
         findTotal.c:43:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’
                     makes pointer from integer without a cast
        /usr/include/stdio.h:271:14: note: expected ‘const 
         char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’
      ```

Please help me with this, thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 int numOfInt;
 char fileName="";

 sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&numOfInt);
 sscanf(argv[2],"%c",&fileName);

 int i, rc;

 /* the origninal list , initialise as 0 index*/
 int inArray[numOfInt];

 /* the number of output int  */
 int outNumInt = numOfInt * 0.1;

 /*  the output array of int  */
 int outArray[outNumInt];


 FILE *inFile;
 inFile = fopen(fileName,"r");

 /*      check if the file is empty      */
 if(inFile==NULL){
    printf("can not open the file");
 }

 for (i = 0; (rc = getc(inFile)) != EOF && i < numOfInt; inArray[i++] = rc) 
 { 


 }//for

 fclose(inFile);

 for(i = 0; i < numOfInt;i++){

    printf("%x\n",inArray[i]);
 }



}//main
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're having? What errors are you getting?

Comment: May I suggest using fscanf to read in the numbers in the file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could be using scanf better here. You use it to read in two pieces of information that should have been passed as arguments to the program, and then refreain from using it for what it would actually be good for, which is reading the file in question. Here is my take at this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) { return *(int*)b - *(int*)a; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * ifile = argv[1];
    int n = atoi(argv[2]), m = n/10, i;
    int nums[n];
    FILE * f = fopen(ifile, "r");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) fscanf(f, "%d", &nums[i]);
    qsort(nums, n, sizeof(int), cmp);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++) printf("%d\n",nums[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

If this file is `prog.c` and the corresponding executable is `prog`, and your file with numbers is called `nums.txt`, and contains `100` integers, you would call this as

```
prog nums.txt 100
```

The advantage of taking in parameters this way is that it makes repeating the command later easier (all the information needed to repeat it will be in the command history of the shell), and that it is the standard way of passing parameters to a program. It also frees up standard input for other uses.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I see in your code is:

```
 char fileName="";
 sscanf(argv[2],"%c",&fileName)
```

A string literal is a *constant* string, which means you shouldn't attempt to modify it, you should either use a static (or dynamic) char array for that string and use the `%s` format specifier, or just point fileName to argv[2]

```
char *fileName;    
fileName = argv[2];
```

Comment: `char fileName=""` does not make any sense. That stores the address of the constant string "" into a char (which is too small to store the address). The sscanf won't try to modify the string literal but only change the value stored in fileName.

Comment: @Maxime it doesn't do what you say exactly but anyway that's not my code, that's the OP's code :) I'm just quoting the problem

Comment: I know, I know. If you think I've said something wrong, feel free to correct me ;).

Comment: @Maxime actually never mind, I didn't read what you said carefully, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed a problem with the filename's management. `char` is for characters; if you want to handle a file name, you have to use a string. In C, we can use an array of `char`, terminated by a nul-character. Here, because `argv[2]` holds directly the name, you can simply use a pointer.

```
char *fileName = argv[2];
```

And then:

```
fopen(fileName, "r");
```

Since you don't modify the `argv` pointer, you can also send directly `argv[2]` as argument.